# How to filter/find string associated with items from the collection and place that matched string into texblock in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am wondering if someone can share with information or good sample with filtering listboxitems based on what is typed in the textbox. Perhaps, it can be a different control that fits better to the scenario below.

In my scenario, I need to type a short string in texblock. Then, click ‘check’ button which will find the closest string values of items from the collection and show these matches in a form of the list below the textblock. Selecting any of items from shown list of items will place the selected string/item in the tetxblock. The behavior is very similar to combox box.

Finally, I need to be able to add that selected string/item that was placed in the texblock to another listbox by clicking ‘Add’ button. Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Below is my XAML code:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
x:Class="FilterListItems.MainPage"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilterListItems"
Width="640" Height="480">

<UserControl.Resources>   
    <local:Products x:Key="productCollection" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="collProducts" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource productCollection}, Path=DataCollection}">
</CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources> 
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0">
  <TextBlock Text="Enter Partial Name: " />
  <TextBox Width="100" Name="txtName" />
  <Button Name="btnSearch" Content="Check" Click="btn_Check" />
  <Button Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Click="btn_Add" Margin="9,0,0,0" />
</StackPanel>
<ListBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Name="lstData" DisplayMemberPath="ProductName"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource collProducts}}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<ListBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Name="2stData" />
```

C# to generate the collection:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //FilterData();
    }
}


public class Product
{
    public Product(int id, string name)
    {
      ProductId = id;
      ProductName = name;
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }

public class Products : List<Product>
{


    public Products()
    {
        InitCollection();
    }

    public List<Product> DataCollection { get; set; }

    List<Product> InitCollection()
    {
        DataCollection = new List<Product>();

        DataCollection.Add(new Product(1, "aaa"));
        DataCollection.Add(new Product(2, "bbb"));
        DataCollection.Add(new Product(3, "ccc"));
        DataCollection.Add(new Product(4, "ddd"));
        DataCollection.Add(new Product(5, "eee"));
        DataCollection.Add(new Product(6, "fff"));
        DataCollection.Add(new Product(7, "hhh"));
        DataCollection.Add(new Product(8, "ggg"));

        return DataCollection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [AutoCompleteBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28VS.95%29.aspx) from [wpftoolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)

also check

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/wpfautocompletebox/

Comment: Thank you Biju. AutoCompleteBox should work for my needs well. I am only wondering if you can suggest on how to move a selected string from AutoCompleteBox to a listbox by clicking a button. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Bea Stollnitz is a great resource for finding out how to filter collections.  You should start with her post on "[How do I filter items from a collection?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31)" to get a simple and clear picture.  When you are done with that article just use the search on her blog to search for "filter"ing collections using collectionviewsource.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the article. It is great article and useful. It looks like that the second suggestion from Biju might fit better my needs. I will experiment with both. I only wondering if you can suggest on moving a selected string from AutoCompleteBox to a listbox by clicking a button.